# Layout type controller does not render scripts

Tags: magento2, layout, ajax

I have a controller which I want to use to load **scripts** via **ajax** however whenever I add scripts to the block within the layout page type all script tags seem to be stripped out.

Is there a way I can load scripts into this controller like this?

> **Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\GDPR\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Tags extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     * 
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
        return $resultLayout;   
    }
}
```

> **xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="tagblock" template="Harrigo_GDPR::scriptblock.phtml" />
    </container>
</layout>
```

> **tagblock.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('beforebodyend')->toHtml();?>
TEST
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello world");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't figure this out but would like to as have had difficulties with certain blocks that I add into layouts include both HTML and JS and so do not function as would expect and this could potentially be the cause.

I found however that using a JSON controller and passing the scripts via json to be more appropriate and am posting this as a workaround for if anyone needs.

> JSON Controller:

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\GDPR\Controller\Index;

class Tags extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $blockId = 'beforebodyend';
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
        $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);
        $html = $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent());
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $result->setData(['tags' => $html]);
        return $result;  
    }
}
```

> Calling the Controller:

```
<div class="non-essential-tag-wrapper">
</div>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/jquery.cookie'], function($){ 
    if ($.cookie('user_allowed_save_cookie')) {
        $.getJSON("/tags/index/tags", function(result){
            $(".non-essential-tag-wrapper").html(result["tags"]);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```